# Conversion of unsigned int to hex string without use of sprintf

Tags: c, string, integer, hex, unsigned

I am trying to implement the following (without `sprintf` or formatting):

```
void integer_to_string(unsigned int a, char *string)
{
    char arr[16] = "0123456789abcdef";
    char *p = (char *)&a;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        unsigned char lo = p[i] & 0xf; 
        unsigned char hi = p[i] >> 4;

        string[i * 2] = arr[hi];
        string[i * 2 + 1] = arr[lo];
    }
    string[2 * i] = '\0';
}
```

This program is converting from an integer `a` and converting `a` into hexadecimal and saving the rest as a string.  So, it is supposed to return an int like `10` to `"0000000a"` but instead is giving me a value of `"0a000000"` instead. What am I doing wrong? How do I move the `0a` to the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: It looks like your system is using little-endian byte order for integers.  You need to either walk the bytes of that value in reverse order, or write the bytes in your string starting from the right-hand side.  Choose one.  For a solution that does not rely on knowing a system's endianness, you can instead use bit shifting and masking to achieve the same thing.

Comment: `char *p = (char *)&a;` This is not portable as the byte of the int that `p` points to depends on the platform [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It appears your platform is little endian so `p` starts off at the lowest byte address. Better to operate with shifts and mask on the entire int.

Comment: There is another problem: when doing bit twiddling **always** use unsigned types. The standard does not specify whether `char` is signed or unsigned. If it is signed (x86!), then `p[i] >> 4` can be arithmetic sign-extended shift and you get something not quite right. If you **are** using x86, try converting 255 to hex

Answer (score 4):

Accessing  the correct significant bytes via `char *p = (char *)&a;`  is endian dependent and in OP's case, the wrong order.

---

Get the order right and avoid endian-ness issues by using math, not casts:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    unsigned char ch = (a >> ((32-4) - i*4)) & 0xF; 
    string[i] = arr[ch];
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Simplification exist.

Comment: Or even better, use CHAR_BIT + sizeof

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but certainly a fast one...

This function returns a `char*` containing the HEX version of any unsigned integer of 32 bits or fewer that is passed to it...

example: `u32tohex(284598256);` will return `"0x10F69FF0"` as char*

the return char[] must be declared outside the function, because returning the pointer of a local variable will not work!

```
char dex[11] = "0x00000000";


const char* u32tohex(uint32_t ul)
{
  const char HexC[17]="0123456789ABCDEF";
  for (uint8_t xh=9; xh>1; xh--)
  {
    dex[xh]=HexC[ul&0xf];
    ul>>=4;
  }
  return &dex;
}
```

or the same without the prefix `"0x"`...
example: `u32tohex(121345243);` will return `"073B94DB"` as char*

```
char dex[9] = "00000000";


const char* u32tohex(uint32_t ul)
{
  const char HexC[17]="0123456789ABCDEF";
  for (uint8_t xh=0; xh<8; xh++) 
  {
    dex[7-xh]=HexC[ul&0xf];
    ul>>=4;
  }
  return &dex;
}
```

Probably, a bit difficult to understand at first glance, but the less manipulation done to variables, will always yield a fast function... the Unsigned integer of 32 bit passed to the function is stored in ul, the loop starts by the end of the char[] result, and going backward... because I only bitwise AND ul with the 0xf, to get the least significant nibble, in one shot and set the final character form the HexC[]... and right shift the ul of 4 bits, getting rid of the last nibble, and replacing it by the next one... only 8 iterations, and the job is done... It may seem useless to have a fast function for this purpose, for a few conventions, but if you use it in a disassembler, to display the address at every line on the screen, as well as the data from those addresses, the speed of the refresh, while scrolling the screen will be very responsive, compared to many other solutions...

Comment: Or you could make it `static`.

Comment: a few: -the function uses external resources and is neither well testable nor thread-safe.  Think early on these! Thus: have the *client* provide the char buffer `dex` and pass it (pointer) to the function, maybe along with its length (safety check), and let the function use the given buffer; -HexC does not need the length 17, just `HexC[]`. - use `int` as the for variable in both (rule: use unsigned only for bit patterns), then you can check for `xh >= 0` in the second example and get rid of `7-xh` (costs time!). No need for explicit 8 bit either, just use the platform's plain `int`.

Comment: another: compressed source code does not make faster execution, but slower readability. Therefore I relieved the lines and added some more indentation. Readers will appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

The output is incorrect because your system uses little endian ordering for the bytes that form the `int` values in memory. This is a very common case nowadays. Casting the address of `a` as a `char *`  leads to non portable code.

You should instead write portable code that does not depend on the internal representation of integers this way:

```
// convert an unsigned int to its hexadecimal representation in a string
// assuming str points to an array of at least 9 bytes
// assuming unsigned int type has 32 bits
// returns its second argument for ease of use in chained expressions
char *integer_to_string(unsigned int a, char *str) {
    str[8] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        str[7 - i] = "0123456789abcdef"[a & 0xF];
        a = a >> 4;
    }
    return str;
}
```